# Wordpress get_search_form() doesn't appear to take parameter into account

Tags: wordpress, search, menu, menuitem

I am creating a menu manually and trying to include the search form.

this is taken from the Wordpress Docs "Building a simple menu list" at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items.

I have added an additional <li> element before completing the menu and added the search form.

```
            // Get the nav menu based on $menu_name (same as 'theme_location' or 'menu' arg to wp_nav_menu)
            // This code based on wp_nav_menu's code to get Menu ID from menu slug

            $menu_name = 'main-menu';

            if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {

                $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

                $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

                $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

                foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                    $title = $menu_item->title;
                    $url = $menu_item->url;
                    $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
                }
                $menu_list .= '<li>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
                $menu_list .= '</ul>';
            } else {
                $menu_list = '<ul><li>No Menu</li></ul>';
            }
            echo $menu_list;
```

The problem is in the output.

<div class="mainnav" role="navigation">

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
  <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" size="40" placeholder="Search" alt="Site Search">
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
</form>
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

</div>

Could someone tell me why the search is printing before the menu even though I specify echo = false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your theme has a searchform.php, you're probably hitting [Ticket #16541](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16541): [get_search_form() ignores $echo if searchform.php exists](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L154).

Your workaround is fine if you're just echoing the search form anyway, but if you need to capture the output in a variable, you can work around this with [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
get_search_form();
$my_search_form = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by taking the get_search_form() out of the echo and printing it in its own php block.

I have a feeling (without fully understanding) that the fact I was echoing a statement that was being echoed in the first place caused this funny behaviour.  Putting it in its own php block and not echoing but just calling it directly fixed the problem:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Would welcome any thoughts, advice or guidance on what has happened?